# ArrayList explicit type argument string can be replaced with <>?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

a newbie here!
I am trying to create an arrayList on Android Studio :

```
ArrayList<String> family = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but it gives me a warning "Explicit type argument string can be replaced with <>" and "This inspection reports all new expressions with type arguments which can be replaced with diamond type <>". I tried to ignore it because it is just a warning but I couldn't add any elements to the Arraylist using ".add" so I assume the Arraylist wasn't even created. I tried restarting Android Studio and stuff but nothing worked! Thanks for your time.

EDIT: the main problem is that when I use "add" it said that it cannot resolve symbol 'add'.
example :

```
family.add("jacob");
```

SOLVED: Thanks everyone for your answers, I uninstalled Android Studio and then reinstalled it and I am not encountering the problem anymore!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain, **in detail**, what "I couldn't add any elements to the Arraylist using ".add"" means.

Comment: '(...) I couldn't add any elements to the Arraylist using ".add" (...)'. What made you come to this observation?

Comment: The warning is trying to tell you to use the diamond operator (`<>`) added to the language in Java 7. See this article from the [Java SE 7 Features and Enhancements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) list: [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html).

Comment: where is this code - is it in the scope of a method? if its not that would explain why `add` cannot be resolved.

Comment: How is my app running on android 4.1 with <>  if this wasn't introduced until java 1.7 and android 4.1 uses older jvm ?

Answer (score 7):

Instead of writing

```
ArrayList<String> family = new ArrayList<String>();
```

you can write

```
ArrayList<String> family = new ArrayList<>();
```

if you're using Java7.

It's called the [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html), and it's just syntactic sugar. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Although this answer teaches OP about the diamond operator, it doesn't cover the main problem of the question, i.e. *"I couldn't add any elements to the Arraylist using ".add""*. As such, it's not a useful answer.

Comment: yes thanks for your answer but as I said in the question I did what you told me to do but the problem is I cant add elements to the arraylist, it says that it cannot resolve symbol "add".

Comment: @Andreas The title of the question is "ArrayList explicit type argument string can be replaced with <>?"

Comment: The title is a summary, and it very often misleading. Read the actual question too.

Comment: @Andreas [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018802/arraylist-explicit-type-argument-string-can-be-replaced-with/43018860?noredirect=1#comment73125640_43018802)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following (invalid) example... this code fails to compile with the error `Cannot resolve symbol add`, same as yours.

```
public class Example
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("family");
}
```

The first statement is legal - it declares and initializes the list when the class is initially created. However, the second statement is not legal - the call to `add` can only be made from within a method.

Here's the corrected example.. the call to `add` has been moved into the constructor (a specific type of method) and the compiler no longer complains that `add` cannot be resolved.

```
public class Example
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public Example()
    {
        list.add("family");
    }
}
```

The problem has nothing to do with the diamond `<>` operator. As others have pointed out, this is "syntactic sugar" that is supposed to make writing code easier. IMHO there is nothing wrong with the redundancy in `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`. My personal preference would be to disable that particular warning.

Comment: apparently the problem was "solved" by reinstalling the IDE .oO(dunno what to think) ... so it seems the problem was something completely different, although this will reproduce what was described.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although the problem was actually fixed when I reinstalled the IDE.

Comment: @trooper How to disable that warning? Using IntelliJ (Android Studio).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
List<String> family=new ArrayList<>();
family.add("jacob");
```

Comment: Did you imported java.util.ArrayList and java.util.List packages?