# How does explicit type argument "<>" work on Android 4.1?

Tags: java, android, java-7, java-6

Hello I was getting a warning in my code like the one referenced below and it says this was introduced in java 1.7 so I removed it to get rid of the warning and tested my app on android 4.1 and it ran, to my knowledge android 4.1 uses jdk/jvm 1.6/6 so how is it possible this runs fine without warning ?[image]

[ArrayList explicit type argument string can be replaced with <>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018802/arraylist-explicit-type-argument-string-can-be-replaced-with?rq=1)

Comment: Could you just use a little more interpunction? I get a little restless while reading it.

Comment: this is what it says "reports all new expressions with type arguments which can be replaced with dimaond type <> such <> syntax is not supported under java 1.6 or earlier JVMs.

Comment: Android devices do not run Java, they run on dex bytecode, and as long as your compile toolchain is able to produce proper dex code from java it's all fine. The toolchain is currently able to turn Java 8 syntax into dex code. That works because most of the nice new syntax things are easy to emulate when you are at the compiler level. There's a lot of syntactic sugar that has no effect on the compiled output. But they can't add APIs that weren't there, for example streams api from `java.util.stream` cannot be used unless your device is recent enough to ship with that code (API >= 24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 7 language features are just "translated" to Java 6. It's called desugaring in Android world.

By the way, [Java 8 is supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html) currently.

Comment: then how come when you try to use lambdas and your minimum api is 16 it says "Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16):" why is different using lambda vs <> ?

Comment: May be you're trying to use Functional Interface, they aren't supported currently even with Java 8. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported_features

Comment: do you know why i have to set targetCompatibility to JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 if my JVM is 1.8 ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're talking about the [Diamond Operator](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java-jdk-7-the-diamond-operator.html). It's not about Android, it's about Java. It's simply meant to reduce Java verbosity by infering the type of generic classes.

From the link:

For example, consider the following assignment statement:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

This is rather lengthy, so it can be replaced with this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> anagrams = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: yes but it says this was not introduced until java 7 , but java 7 doesn't work on android 4.1 so how is it still compiling and running fine on my android 4.1 device ?