# FlinkRuntimeException thrown when using EvictingQueue for rolling average

Tags: java, apache-flink, guava, flink-streaming

In a Flink KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction function, I am trying to maintaing the rolling average of the last N entries using [EvictingQueue](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.java) (specifically version 29).

Each record in the Stream has an attribute count. My objective is to calculate the rolling average of the last N records' count attribute.

Here is a stripped down version of the code (other lines removed for clarity):

```
public class PacingController extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunctionKeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<> {

    private ValueState<EvictingQueue<Double>> lastNCountAvg;

    public void open(Configuration conf) {
    ValueStateDescriptor<EvictingQueue<Double>> descriptor =
            new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                "last-n-count",
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<>() {}));
        lastNCountAvg = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
    }

    public void processElement(....ReadOnlyContext readOnlyContext,
                           Collector<BidPacingThresholdPerASUOutput> collector) throws Exception {    
  if(lastNCountAvg.value() == null){      
      lastNCountAvg.update(EvictingQueue.create(10)); //initialize here
   }

   public void onTimer(
        long timestamp,
        OnTimerContext context,
        Collector<> out) throws Exception {
        //update the latest count here.
        EvictingQueue<Double> lastNCountAvgQueue = lastNCountAvg.value();
                lastNCountAvgQueue.add(count);
                lastNCountAvg.update(lastNBidFrequenciesQueue); //Error happens here.
        }
}
```

I have ensured that the EvictingQueue is initialized if null. However when adding a new entry I see the following error:

```
Caused by: TimerException{org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Error while adding data to RocksDB}
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Error while adding data to RocksDB
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.update(RocksDBValueState.java:109)
    at inmarket.bidpacing.streaming.pacing.RollingAverageController.onTimer(PacingController.java:410)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.onProcessingTime(CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.java:152)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.InternalTimerServiceImpl.onProcessingTime(InternalTimerServiceImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1432)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.collect.ForwardingCollection.size(ForwardingCollection.java:65)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:65)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:22)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:599)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValueInternal(AbstractRocksDBState.java:158)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.update(RocksDBValueState.java:107)
    ... 17 more
```

Is this a known issue? Can you please suggest some workarounds to maintaining the rolling average? I am trying to keep the approach of maintaining the rolling list (manually removing older elements) as the last option.

Answer (score 0):

In the line that blows up

```java
lastNCountAvg.update(lastNBidFrequenciesQueue);
```

I don't see that you have initialized `lastNBidFrequenciesQueue` anywhere. Seems like you intended to do this, instead:

```java
lastNCountAvg.update(lastNCountAvgQueue);
```

Comment: I have tried this. I get the same error. This is not the issue, as the explicit type argument "EvictingQueue<Double>" can be replaced with <>. Please refer this example answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018860/6352160